# Maximum Matching in a weighted Tree in O(n)

Tags: algorithm, tree, max, matching, weighted

is there an algorithm in O(n) to calculate the maximum matching for a **weighted** Tree?

I only found algorithms for unweighted trees or bipartite graphs. I have some trouble converting these algorithms for trees.
With pen and paper i also found out, that the algorithm for unweighted trees does not work for weighted trees.
I think recursively it would take more than O(n), what are the alternatives? Dynamic Programming maybe?

Help would be much appreciated.
Thank you :)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/320561/71165

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The O(n) dynamic programming solution is to choose any node as the root, and then recursively calculate the maximum matching in each node's subtree in the root-matched and root-unmatched conditions.

The calculation is easy in postorder (DFS):  The max root-unmatched matching for a node is just the sum of the best matchings for each child subtree. The max root-matched matching for a node is the best matching with the root matched to the root-unmatched subtree for one of its children, added to the best matchings from the other children.